# How to merge dataframes in R when empty strings exist

Tags: r

I have, as the output of a complicated process, two data files that basically look like this:

```
date1 <- c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-02", "", "")
X1 <- c("foo", "bar", "", "")
date2 <- c("", "", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-04")
X2 <- c("", "", "bar", "foo")

file1 <- data.frame(date = date1, X = X1)
file2 <- data.frame(date = date2, X = X2)

> file1
        date   X
1 2021-01-01 foo
2 2021-01-02 bar
3               
4               
> file2
        date   X
1               
2               
3 2021-01-03 bar
4 2021-01-04 foo
```

Note that the blank rows are empty strings, not NAs. Also note that, in my real-life data, all blank rows in file 1 have data in file 2, and all blank rows in file 2 have data in file 1.

What I want is to merge these data by replacing the empty strings with the data from the other file:

```
desired_date <- c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-02", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-04")
desired_X <- c("foo", "bar", "bar", "foo")
desired <- data.frame(date = desired_date, X = desired_X)

> desired
        date   X
1 2021-01-01 foo
2 2021-01-02 bar
3 2021-01-03 bar
4 2021-01-04 foo
```

I feel like I could do this if the missing data were NA, but the empty strings seem to be messing me up. Help?

Comment: Maybe instead of merging you can try `dplyr::bind_rows(file1, file2)`, that way you don't lose any data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the order of these your two data frames is going to be stable, this can be done just by selecting the missing rows and filling them with the corresponding non-empty rows from the other one.

```
file3 <- file1
file3[file3$date == "", ] <- file2[file2$date != "", ]
file3

# 
# date   X
# 1 2021-01-01 foo
# 2 2021-01-02 bar
# 3 2021-01-03 bar
# 4 2021-01-04 foo
```

I've created a new object called `file3` just in case you don't want to modify your original. If you don't mind overwriting the original, this can be shortened down as:

```
file1[file1$date == "", ] <- file2[file2$date != "", ]
```

Edit: @jay.sf asks how this would work with NA in the data. I've extended the OP's original example to show how I would handle NA in my approach:

```
date1 <- c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-02", "", "", NA)
X1 <- c("foo", "bar", "", "", NA)
date2 <- c("", "", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-04", "2021-01-05")
X2 <- c("", "", "bar", "foo", "bar")

file1 <- data.frame(date = date1, X = X1)
file2 <- data.frame(date = date2, X = X2)

file1
# > file1
# date    X
# 1 2021-01-01  foo
# 2 2021-01-02  bar
# 3                
# 4                
# 5       <NA> <NA>

file2
# > file2
# date   X
# 1               
# 2               
# 3 2021-01-03 bar
# 4 2021-01-04 foo
# 5 2021-01-05 bar

file3 <- file1
empty_rows <- file1$date == "" | is.na(file1$date)
file3[empty_rows, ] <- file2[empty_rows, ]
file3

# > file3
# date   X
# 1 2021-01-01 foo
# 2 2021-01-02 bar
# 3 2021-01-03 bar
# 4 2021-01-04 foo
# 5 2021-01-05 bar
```

I've consolidated it a bit by creating the object `empty_rows`, which is a logical indicating rows in `file1` that have empty text or `NA`.

Comment: What does your code produce if there are `NA`s, say `file3[3, 1] <- NA`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bind_rows` to bind the datasets `file1` and `file2` by row. Adding the `id` variable allows us to get rid of the empty rows by filtering on `date`.

```r
library(dplyr)

file1 %>% 
  bind_rows(file2) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  filter(!(date == "")) %>% 
  select(date, X)

#>         date   X
#> 1 2021-01-01 foo
#> 2 2021-01-02 bar
#> 3 2021-01-03 bar
#> 4 2021-01-04 foo
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could write a small helper function `f` to wrap around the data frames in `merge`.

```
f <- function(x) x[rowSums(x == "", na.rm=T) == 0, ]

merge(f(file1), f(file2), all=TRUE)
#        date   X
# 1 2021-01-01 foo
# 2 2021-01-02 bar
# 3 2021-01-03 bar
# 4 2021-01-04 foo
```